# What paint should I use over decorator's caulk so that it matches the surrounding area?

Tags: painting, paint, caulking

I have some overzealous use of [decorator's caulk](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Decorators-Caulk-White-310ml/p/240693) that I wish to paint over. However when I paint over it, it comes up cracked, and more importantly a darker shade so it's obvious.

What type of paint should I be buying to paint over it?

Answer (score 1):

The caulk mentioned in your comment appears to be a typical latex "painters caulk". It should accept paint just fine, with no bleed-through. I'm not sure what's happening in your case.

I'd get a quart of a high-grade primer such as a Zinsser product. There are plenty of good ones. Cover just the caulk and blend into the wall. Let that dry well and try your topcoat again.

If you painted over the caulk entirely you may need to use a paint remover to clean that up first.

Answer (score 0):

Wipe with xylene and then apply a coat of solvent based primer and let cure 3 days for outgassing. Add another coat of regular latex primer and then paint per primer and paint manufacturer instructions. I was a Waterproofer for years sealants was my game☺  also remember if spanning a flat joint, imagine a flat brick wall with expansion joints.  Use backer rod and remember the caulk should only be 1/2 as deep as the width of joint so the caulk can stretch.  This rule also applies for large angle joints like slab to wall, you must use a bondbreaker tape at the back of the angle so the caulk only adheres to outer edges and use same 1/2 of joint caulk finished tooling size. And always tool your caulk both directions to make it bite into the surface.